# Sum of all combination in SQL Server without repeating same values

Tags: sql-server, combinations

This link does provide a close solution:

[Sql Query : Sum , all the possible combination of rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906369/sql-query-sum-all-the-possible-combination-of-rows-in-a-table)

The logic here is

```
n! / k!(n-k)!     where k = 1 to n
```

But I want the values which are not repeating

Example: TEMPTABLE

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 5000  |
| 2  | 5000  |
| 3  | 5000  |
| 4  | 5000  |
+----+-------+
```

For this table K should be 1 because only one way you can arrange the set

So the combination will be

```
5000
5000 + 5000 = 10000

5000 + 5000 + 5000 = 15000

5000 + 5000 + 5000 + 5000 = 20000
```

Total of 4 combinations

```
4! / 1!(4-1)! = 4
```

For the answer above the combination will be

```
= 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 15
```

11 of those will be same results

Problem will be if more number of entries are there the execution time will be more, so I want to remove those repeating totals while calculating the total.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a distinct or a group by depending what do you need

```
--To get the values
;With selfrec as (
  Select t.Value, t.ID, 0 as Level From #TempTable t
       UNION ALL
  Select t2.Value + t1.Value as Value, t1.ID, Level + 1 From #TempTable t1 
  Inner Join selfrec t2 on t1.ID < t2.ID 
  Where Level < 4 -- limit the number of recursions
)
Select Value 
From selfrec
Group by value 

-- To get the number of combinations 
;With selfrec as (
  Select t.Value, t.ID, 0 as Level From #TempTable t
       UNION ALL
  Select t2.Value + t1.Value as Value, t1.ID, Level + 1 From #TempTable t1 
  Inner Join selfrec t2 on t1.ID < t2.ID 
  Where Level < 4 -- limit the number of recursions
)
Select COUNT(DISTINCT Value) 
From selfrec
```

Comment: Problem will be if more number of entries are there the execution time will be more, so I want to remove those repeating totals while calculating the total.

Comment: Is a recursive function, you'll need to calculate each combination anyway, adding that validation to the CTE would have more impact in the performance than this, also, in a recursive CTE is not possible to use the recursive expression more than once (ex, to add an EXISTS condition)

Comment: Ok, but can we do this without **Recursive CTE** than?

Comment: The other way is using temp tables and loops, but anyway they need to iterate for all combinations and check if the value already exists, the cost will be the same. I think that this is the best option